# How to accept a paypal transaction automatically

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

Is their a way that i can accept a paypal transaction automatically without going to the paypal dashboard and click on accept?Like calling an API ?Thanks

Comment: are these paymeny via your website? what type of transaction?

Comment: The payments are via my paypal email address but not on my website.I am receiving paypal ipn notifications in my IPN handler .Everytime  the transaction status comes indicated 'pending' and it makes me go to paypal dashboard to accept the payment.Its a send money transaction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

convert your paypal account to a business account. its free.

1. Log in to your PayPal account.
2. Click the Profile icon next to "Log out."
3. Click Upgrade to a business account.
4. Enter your business information and click Continue.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I managed this feat (100,000 experience points).

My Profile -> My Selling preferences -> Website Preferences.

[image]

And then I added a Return URL, Switched on 'Block Non-encrpyted Website'. Unclear which action solved the problem.

Good luck.

[image]